# Feature Selection: AttributeError when trying to see which columns have been retained

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, sklearn-pandas

I am getting an error when trying to apply feature selection to my classification model. I think this error is a simple one, easy to solve, but I am unsure how to fix it.

This is my code:

```
X = df[['S_LENGTH', 'S_WIDTH', 'P_LENGTH', 'P_WIDTH']].values
y = df['SPECIES'].values

feature_select = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=20).fit(X, y)
```

But when I try execute this to view the retained features...

```
feature_select = X.columns[selection.get_support()]
print(features)
```

...I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

Any help on how to fix this error is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you define `X` you take the values from the pandas DataFrame `df`. The values are a `numpy.ndarray` and as such have no property `columns`.

To fix you need to update your line `feature_select = X.columns[selection.get_support()]`.

It should read `features = df.columns[feature_select.get_support()]`.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the response, but I get ```NameError: name 'selection' is not defined``` when executing the code you told me to use.

Comment: Hi @Bono I've edited my code to fix this. There were two issues - 1. You want to print `features` so we assign the subset of columns to this variable. 2. `selection` doesn't exist and should have read `feature_select`.